# pandas math operation with where condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do math on a condition in a dataframe, but I couldn't.

my code:

```
open_position=df.loc[df['sale_price'].isna(), 'purchase_price'*'amount'].sum()
```

I want to do. Multiply `df['purchase_price']` and `df['amount']` in rows where `df['sales_price']` is `NaN` and get the sum of all these.

it gives the following error.

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Can you help with this?

Comment: `m = df['sale_price'].isna(); (df.loc[~m, 'purchase_price']*df.loc[~m, 'amount']).sum()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
df.loc[df['sale_price'].isna(), 'purchase_price'].mul(df['amount']).sum()
```

or

```py
df['product'] = df['purchase_price'] * df['amount']
df.loc[df['sale_price'].isna(), 'product'].sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df.loc[df['sale_price'].isna()].apply(lambda row: row['purchase_price'] * row['amount'], axis=1).sum()
```

Test dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sale_price':[10, np.nan, 30], 'purchase_price':[5, 15, 25], 'amount':[1, 2, 3]})
```